# Visual Basic 2008, Random sting generator with custom length, how to make it?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I want to make random string with custom length.
How do i customize the string length? I tried like this:

```
    TextBox1.MaxLength = TextBox2.Text

    Dim random As New Random
    Dim password As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For i As Int32 = 1000 To 3000
        password.Append(Chr(random.Next(65, 90)))
        password.Append(Chr(random.Next(48, 57)))
        password.Append(Chr(random.Next(97, 122)))
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = password.ToString
```

but its always comes with 6003 length.

Comment: (3000 - 1000) = 2001; you append 3 chars in each iteration, so 3 x 2001 = 6003

Answer (score 0):

Now your length is fixed - you run the loop `For i As Int32 = 1000 To 3000` (i.e. 2001 times) and then add 3 symbols in each loop, which gives you `3 x 2001 = 6003` length.

Easiest way would be to define the array of the symbols that are allowed and then combine random number of these:

```
Dim random As New Random
Dim password As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim allowedSymbols as Integer() = {48, 49, ..., 122}    ' Define the list of allowed symbols
Dim length = random.Next(10, 50)    'length of the string - from 10 to 50 symbols
For i As Int32 = 0 To length
    password.Append(Chr(allowedSymbols(random.Next(allowedSymbols.Length))))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a static `For Loop` to append characters (3 characters everytime, for 2001 times). This will allow you to customize your length:

```
    Dim random As New Random
    Dim password As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim customLength As Long = InputBox("Insert your length: ")
    For i As Int32 = 1 To customLength
        password.Append(Chr(random.Next(65, 90)))
        password.Append(Chr(random.Next(48, 57)))
        password.Append(Chr(random.Next(97, 122)))
    Next

    MsgBox(password.ToString)
```

However, please note that you append 3 new chars at every iteration. So of course, if you insert "5" as custom length, the password will have 15 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the mistake in your length calculation.  Try this.

```
Private Function GenPassword(customLength As Integer) As String
    Static prng As New Random
    Dim password As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    Const theNums As String = "0123456789"
    Const theUpperLetters As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Const theLowerLetters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    '
    Do While password.Length < customLength
        password.Append(theUpperLetters(prng.Next(theUpperLetters.Length)))
        password.Append(theLowerLetters(prng.Next(theLowerLetters.Length)))
        password.Append(theNums(prng.Next(theNums.Length)))
    Loop
    Return password.ToString.Substring(0, customLength)
End Function
```

Note that I did not use numeric values for characters and that only one Random is created.